# Why is this writing a line number to the new file?

Tags: string, batch-file, file-io

This basically takes a file as input (%textfile%) and steps through each line, replacing any instance of %search% with %replace%.  It works well, however it is writing line numbers. See sample i/o below code.

I found this code elsewhere.  I thought I was fairly decent at batch scripting, but I'm not familiar with what the ! is doing.

```
(for /f "delims=" %%i in ('findstr /n "^" "%textfile%"') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
    echo(!line!
    endlocal
))>"%newfile%"
```

Input file:

```
:host {
  display: block;
}

/* To ensure your styling works under the Shadow DOM polyfill, see
   www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/styling.html#directives */
polyfill-next-selector { content: ':host > h2'; }
::content h2 {
  color: blue;
}
```

Output file:

```
1::host {
2:  display: block;
3:}
4:
5:/* To ensure your styling works under the Shadow DOM polyfill, see
6:   www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/styling.html#directives */
7:polyfill-next-selector { content: ':host > h2'; }
8:::content h2 {
9:  color: blue;
10:}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the cause. From `findstr /?`:

```
/N         Prints the line number before each line that matches.
```

Your command has it:

```
'findstr /n "^" "%textfile%"'
```

Comment: Awesome! I thought it would be something simple, thanks!

Comment: I'll accept your answer when the stupid 10 minute timer expires